# Rendering CDATA HTML tag from KML file in android map api v2 not working

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, kml

In my project I am using KML file from raw folder to render in MapView API V2. But it is not rendering ![CDATA] tag with value of given variable instead it display variable itself.
Following is my KML file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
<Document>
  <name>Data+BalloonStyle</name>
  <Style id="golf-balloon-style">
     <IconStyle>
            <color>ff3644DB</color>
            <scale>1.1</scale>
            <Icon>
                <href>http://www.gstatic.com/mapspro/images/stock/503-wht-blank_maps.png</href>
            </Icon>
            <hotSpot x='16' y='31' xunits='pixels' yunits='insetPixels'>
            </hotSpot>
        </IconStyle>
     <BalloonStyle>
         <bgColor>ffffffbb</bgColor>
          <text><![CDATA[
          <b><font color="#CC0000" size="+3">$[name]</font></b>
          <br/><br/>
          <font face="Courier">$[description]</font>
          <br/><br/>
          Extra text that will appear in the description balloon
          <br/><br/>$[geDirections]
          ]]></text>

    </BalloonStyle>
  </Style>
  <Placemark>
    <name>Club house</name>
     <description>An example of BalloonStyle</description>
     <styleUrl>#golf-balloon-style</styleUrl>
     <ExtendedData>
      <Data name="geDirections">
        <value>1</value>
      </Data>
      <Data name="holeYardage">
        <value>234</value>
      </Data>
      <Data name="holePar">
        <value>4</value>
      </Data>
    </ExtendedData>
    <Point>
        <coordinates>103.80148899999995,1.440409,0.0</coordinates>
    </Point>
  </Placemark>
  <Placemark>
    <name>By the lake</name>
    <description>An example of BalloonStyle</description>
    <styleUrl>#golf-balloon-style</styleUrl>
    <ExtendedData>
      <Data name="geDirections">
        <value>5</value>
      </Data>
      <Data name="holeYardage">
        <value>523</value>
      </Data>
      <Data name="holePar">
        <value>5</value>
      </Data>
    </ExtendedData>
    <Point>
            <coordinates>103.90148899999995,1.440409,0.0</coordinates>
    </Point>
  </Placemark>
</Document>
</kml>
```

It display infowindow with variable name $[name],$[description] and [geDirections] itself.Following is the output :
[image]

Please provide some information regarding this issue.
Thanks!

Comment: Check this https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kml_tut#using-the-cdata-element

Comment: I gone through this. None of this works. May be it is an issue in Android which does not render a variable value from KML. I have tried almost everything

Answer (score 0):

Go through:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/utility/kml

Its clearly mentioned that $[dataname] is not supported

"Plain text only, no HTML content is supported"

"untyped  only, no  or , and entity replacements of the form$[dataName] are unsupported."

Comment: Even after 2 years, the state is still the same. If only we are able to change the placemark content view.